# Why does the React Native TextInput text shift when updating value using state?

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput that is having some strange behavior when updating its value with onChangeText. Here is some example code:

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("some test string that i");
<TextInput
    placeholder="Type something in"
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={(text) => setInputText(text)}
    value={inputText}
    numberOfLines={1}
 />
```

When I place the cursor between one of the words and start typing, the extra characters get added but then the text gets shifted backwards. Compare this with any other text input anywhere else and when adding more text, the characters behind the additional text does not get shifted backwards as you type.

This is on iOS.

Comment: Howdy, did you ever figure this one out?